# Ruby split array then return first element based on pattern

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a languages string, defined as: `en,fr,nl_nl`. I need to return the first element that starts with `nl`. How can I do this?

I've started with `languages.split(',')`, but don't know what's the best way to search for a pattern in an array and return the first element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work as you expect:

```
languages.split(',').detect { |s| s.start_with?('nl') }
# => "nl_nl"
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you need the array, you could use a regular expression to find the substring:

```
languages = 'en,fr,nl_nl'
languages[/\bnl[^,]*/] #=> "nl_nl"
languages[/\ben[^,]*/] #=> "en"
```